# Video call through the body of tegram api

Tags: api, raspberry-pi, telegram, tdlib

I would like to know whether it is possible to start a video call with another user by means of the tdlib library and transfer a picture from a camera connected to a Raspberry Pi to this call? And if so, how do you do that? What methods should I use?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here are the python sources With working code of video translator with youtube/m3ui/mp4
https://github.com/EverythingSuckz/tgvc-video-tests

Answer (score 3):

To work with video calls part of Telegram you need to use Telegram's WebRTC client (https://github.com/TelegramMessenger/tgcalls). With MTProto methods you can get params to start this library. Video and audio bytes passing via this library.

There is already implemented high level library for Python that works with official tgcalls library. But working with private calls in a TODO list. You can use this project as an example how to work with tgcalls library.

https://github.com/MarshalX/tgcalls